# How to combine multiple find() in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have these two conditions:

1) Find all div with a "data-filter-program" attribute which equal to something
2) Find all div with a "data-filter-expertise" attribute which equal to something

And I need to somehow combine these two into one statement in jquery. I would like something like this:

```
mentors = $("div").find("[data-filter-program*='"+selected_program+"']" && "[data-filter-expertise*='"+selected_expertise+"']");
```

How do I actually achieve this correctly in Jquery?

Thanks!

Comment: Not hard to look this up in [selectors api](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/basic-css-selectors/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mentors = $("div").find("[data-filter-program*='"+selected_program+"'], [data-filter-expertise*='"+selected_expertise+"']");
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a comma between each item you would like to find.

```
$("div").find("#apples, #bananas, .grapes, div");
```